# Replacing rails controller tests for integration test should always persist to db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm finding Rails integration tests relevant for testing flows and I have some questions about the industry standard on replacing controller test (deprecated in rails 5) with integration tests.

Usually we have tiny controllers where we get the parameters, call the right collaborator and prepare the response and it is easy to test it by mocking the collaborator directly on the controller object.

I am concerned about the overhead of migrating every controller test to integration test that persist the db. What are the standards for this case?

Whats the standard when testing just one route/action and not a complete flow?

How can we replace this?:

> ```
> @controller.stubs(:authenticate).returns(true)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Integration tests are intended to mimic a *real user*. They're meant to test the entire application in their entirety.

Opinion varies on what this means. To me, it means you should avoid stubbing/mocking completely. Not a single thing stubbed or mocked, everything executed in full. This means that every integration test I write goes through the actual authentication process of typing in a username and password. Some of the steps are redundant, yes.

Integrations tests are slower all around than unit/controller tests. Cutting out the authentication steps likely won't save you enough time to make a difference in the long run (no pun intended).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. Agree in everything. Authentication and storing users wont make the difference but storing every model in db when migrating controller tests to integration tests (as suggested in Rails 5) is a lot of overhead. Do you make a rails integration test storing everything to the db for every controller action??

Comment: @Jorge I use fixtures/factories to create only what I need for the current test.